# Count if in excel - EXCEL formula

Tags: excel-2010

I have two columns with different values in excel as shown below.

[image]

I want the output to be as below :

[image]

I understand this is conditional counting in excel and would require playing around with `countif` . But so so far I haven't been able to come up with the exact solution. Can anyone help please.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx section "Common formulas" `=COUNTIF(A2:A5,A4)` does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use COUNTIFS because you have two criteria ranges.

[image: COUNTIFS example]

Using a pivot table:

Insert PivotTable
Select a table or range
  Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10
Choose where you want the PivotTable report to be placed
  Existing Worksheet
  Location: Sheet1!$A$18

Drag Column A to `Column Labels`
Drag Column B to `Row Labels`
Drag Column B to `Values`
Click dropdown next to `Count of Column B`, select `Summarize Values By`, set it to `Count`.
Click `Number Format`, select `Number`, set Decimal places to 0.

[image]

The only problem is that the pivot table doesn't show the 0 values. There's probably a way to fix that.

Comment: Mate this covers most of the answer. 1 point missed out though , Values on column A and Column B aren't limited to 2 and 4 values respoectively . Is there anyway , we can make the formula figure it out and cretae the table accordingly?

Comment: Ah, if the number of possible values for Column A (Type 1, Type 2, ...) and for Column B (A, B, ...) are not fixed, then perhaps it might be easier to use a pivot table.

Comment: Edited original answer to include pivot table.